# MonoDevelop and AjaxControlToolkit: Register Server Tag in Mono

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I know that Mono supports the AjaxControlToolkit but I don't know how to integrate it into MonoDevelop. I added AjaxControlToolkit.dll, System.Web.Extensions.dll and System.Web.Extensions.Design.dll as References in the project but when I build the project I get the warning:

/Users/user1/Projects/FirstProject/Default.aspx(1,1): Warning: Parser failed with error The tag type 'ajaxToolkit:TabContainer' has not been registered.. CodeBehind members for this file will not be added. (FirstProject)

and I when I deploy it I get the error:  Unknown server tag 'ajaxToolkit:TabContainer'.
How do I register the server tag in MonoDevelop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either the `<%@Register` directive, or add some lines to your `Web.config`.  [See here](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/11/14/register_custom_controls_in_web.config.aspx) for instructions on either approach.

Using the `Web.config` mechanism has the advantage that you don't need to add a directive to every page where you want to use the controls.

Comment: I looked at your link but I am not sure what to specify for the Src property and/or the Assembly property.

Comment: You would not use the TagName form for imported controls in another assembly, so don't worry about the Src property.  For the Assembly property, just put the assembly name.  This would probably be AjaxControlToolkit.

Comment: So the full line, if you are going the <%@Register route, would be something like  <%@ Register TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" %>

Comment: That seemed to fix that warning but I am now getting this error when I run: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "AjaxControlToolkit.Properties.Resources.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "AjaxControlToolkit" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

Comment: Not sure I can help you with that one... maybe it's worthy of a new question?

Comment: I found out what was going on: Missing ScriptManager. Thanks for your help cdhowie!

Comment: No problem!  Good luck with the project.